# Preloaded images are not beeing used

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to preload images for use in a image gallery. The images are taken threw a php script from a folder outside of the htdocs folder. And when they are loaded the images should be used in a masonry layout.

As far as my knowledge goes the javascript that I am using should be working. However when I am using the page on a gallery for several 100 images it does not work. Some images are loaded others are not.

I also have very little knowledge of javascript in general. So any advice would be helpful.

I tried a lot of things. The imagesloaded from desandro. Several iterations of the script I will share on the bottom. I am at a loss.

Javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var images = <?php echo json_encode($images); ?>;
    var folder = <?php echo json_encode($folderName); ?>;
    var imageArray = [];

    function preloadImages() {
        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            var img[i] = new Image();
            img[i].src = "img/jpg/" + folder + "/" + images[i].image_name;;
            imageArray.push(img);
        }
    }
</script>
```

JSON example (for the images)

```
{"image_id":"8","image_name":"DSC00058.JPG","image_selected":"1","image_locked":"0"},
{"image_id":"9","image_name":"DSC00053.JPG","image_selected":"1","image_locked":"1"},
```

HTML

```
<body class="h-100 bg-light" onload="preloadImages();">
```

The expected result would be that the masonry only starts building and using the images that are preloaded. Is there a way to use the preloaded images or do I need to doe a specific thing in HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Your preload function is loading the images, but it's not *pre*loading them. The trick is to wait for them all to load before initializing the masonry plugin..

Here's an example using promises.

```
function preloadImages() {
  var promises = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    promises.push(new Promise(done => {
      var img[i] = new Image();
      img.onload = ()=>done();
      img[i].src = "img/jpg/" + folder + "/" + images[i].image_name;;
      imageArray.push(img);
    }));
  }
  Promise.all(promises).then(()=>{
    // initialize masonry here...
  });
}
```

Comment: I believe i forgot a important part
I use this :: <body class="h-100 bg-light" onload="preloadImages();">

Comment: var grid = document.querySelector('.grid');

            msnry = new Masonry(grid, {
            itemSelector: '.grid-item',
            columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
            percentPosition: true,
            gutter: 10
            });
It is not loading at all now :)

Comment: are you sure? maybe it's just taking some time. you said you had several hundred images, that could take several seconds, if not several minutes, to load.

Comment: Well it could be but i am testing localy. And for one or another reason all images are also loading in the page.

Comment: if you can duplicate the issue in a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) i'd be happy to take a peek.

Comment: Thats a bit hard as i get the images from behind the htdocs folder and get all the info out of php. But tnx for the help anyway.